# Dictsort not working right with datetimes returned from model property

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I've got one model that has a datetime:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='meeting start time')
```

and the foreign object, which accesses the datetime (getting the earliest start_time):

```
class Section(models.Model):
    def calculate_start_date(self):
        try:
            start = Meeting.objects.filter(section__id=self.id).order_by('start_time')[0].start_time
            return start                          
        except IndexError:
            start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            return start
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    first_start_date = property(calculate_start_date)

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now, when I use this in my template like this:

```
{% for course in course_list %}
    {{ course.title }}
    {% for section in course.section_set.all %}
        {{ section.first_start_date }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

it will print out dates for all of the sections. If there is a section with no meetings linked to it, it prints out the current date.

My problem arises though when I try to introduce dictsort to sort the meetings within a course by time:

```
{% for course in course_list %}
    {{ course.title }}
    {% for section in course.section_set.all|dictsort:"first_start_date" %}
        {{ section.first_start_date }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This properly displays for any course for which all of its sections have at least one meeting, but fails to display properly for any course which has any sections that do not have a meeting linked to them.

I'm confused here since the first template seemed to indicate that datetimes (of the current time) were being provided when a section didn't have a meeting linked to it, but in the second template, it's acting like this isn't the case.

Why is the dictsort failing here?

Comment: Waht means "fails to display properly"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out what was going on.

I've got Django set to timezone aware, so it was giving me time zone aware dates from the database when there was a meeting attached to the section, but when there was no such meeting, I was providing the date as:

```
start = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

which is timezone unaware.

Dictsort was silently failing when comparing time zone aware and time zone unaware dates.

Now that I've switched to providing a timezone aware date, it's working:

```
start = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the implementation of the `dictsort` requires `course.section_set.all` to be an iterable.

However, if there aren't any section attached to `course`, `course.section_set.all` would return `None` instead of an empty iterator, making `course.section_set.all|dictsort` fail.

You need to test `course.section_set.count` is postive and filter `course.section_set.all` conditionally.